# How to test a second PBX securely?

Tags: pbx

I would like to test a second PBX software without causing damage to current company PBX.

For instance, i would like to be sure that if I install this second PBX, all my company phones don't start to register theirself to this new PBX ...

In your opinion is it safe to install a second PBX on same infrastructure ? 
What I need to be careful to avoid..damage ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like any technology in a professional environment you need a test/reference infrastructure to conduct this kind of work on knowing it CAN'T impact production - it's as simple as that, a separate setup for testing.

Comment: "In your opinion.." - doesn't that mean close for "primarily opinion based"? ;) :)

Answer (score 0):

To test a second PBX securely, you should follow these steps:

1. Isolate the second PBX from the production environment by setting up a separate network for testing.
2. Use secure protocols such as VPN or SSH to access the testing network.
3. Use a firewall to restrict access to the testing network to only authorized personnel.
4. Use strong and unique passwords for all PBX and network devices.
5. Regularly update the software and firmware on the PBX and network devices to ensure they are secure.
6. Use monitoring and logging tools to track and detect any suspicious activity on the testing network.
7. Conduct regular security audits and penetration testing to identify and address any vulnerabilities.
   After the testing is completed, ensure to properly decommission the test PBX, clear all the data and configurations.